# How to customize the color of an HTML output file generated from Git Bash?

Tags: git-bash, vim-syntax-highlighting, vimdiff

I have used the following command in Git Bash to perform a 'vimdiff' for 2 XML files.

```
vimdiff  xml1.xml xml2.xml -c TOhtml -c 'w! result.html' -c 'qa!'
```

The HTML file which is getting generated is too flashy. The differences are highlighted in Magenta and the background is Black in color. Also the font colors are Cyan and Green. Is there a way to modify the color settings, so that the result file doesn't contain too many bright colors?

Below are the things which I have tried out, but it doesn't give the required result.

1. Tried changing the 'Foreground' and 'Background' color in the Bash terminal and then performed the vimdiff operation. But the HTML file still contains bright colors.
2. In Vim editor checked for :help :colorscheme, :help :TOhtml, :help :highlight but not sure what exactly should be changed.
3. I found that most of the sites mention about changing the .vimrc file. I was able to locate the '.vimrc' file but not sure what changes should be made to the file.

Is there any resolution for the problem?

HTML output

[image]

Comment: This is not programming related. It might be better to ask this on https://vi.stackexchange.com/ or someplace that focuses on vim configuration.

Comment: @omajid Thanks for replying. I have cross-posted this to vi.stackexchange.com